# Sitemap 0.9 - external links

Tags: seo, sitemap

I am generating sitemap for my web according to http://www.sitemaps.org/.
Is it possible to have in the sitemap external links?
Or the sitemap always include only the internal links.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: This is not about programming and instead something more in tune for Webmasters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to *sitemaps.org*:

> Sitemaps are an easy way for webmasters to inform search engines about pages on **their** sites that are available for crawling.

So, you should not include external URLs to your sitemap at all.